# How to use high-frequency pass filter to select only certain features?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Say I have a picture with some kind of irregularly repeating pattern with different bits "sticking out" at different scales. The diffuse grainy texture in the back and the larger splotches in the background. I would like to be able to create a selection to different level of details to colorize different scales differently.

I know that the high-frequency pass filter is able to capture this kind of pattern, but how can I generate a selection from it?

[image: example]

Comment: Use levels to increase contrast of the layer (so the mid-gray is black). Invert if desired. Copy into a layer mask.

Comment: What is the purpose of this effort? Is this for artistic purposes? Or perhaps scientific imaging?

Comment: It's artistic, I'd like to try coloring this picture and make it look like an archipelago in the sea